# How to change the path when NavLink is active

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

```
<NavLink
   className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? "isActive" : "isNotActive")}
   to={"artist/" + currentMotive.artist.slug.current}
   key={currentMotive.artist.slug.current}>
   {currentMotive.artist.name}
</NavLink>
```

How can I change the attribute `to` in the same way as `className`?
Like:

```
to={({ isActive }) =>
   isActive
      ? "/motive/" + currentMotive.slug.current
      : "artist/" + currentMotive.artist.slug.current
}
```

I use react router 6.8.

I tried to use `useLocation` to check the path and compare it, but isn't there an easier way?

Here is the code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/toogle-navlink-p5plsq?file=/src/RootLayout.js

I want, that in the Nav, Artist 1 works like a toggle to open and close `<Artist />`

Comment: The `to` prop doesn't take a function callback like this. Can you [edit] to explain the use case, what you are trying to accomplish? If you are changing the link target then it will no longer match and be the active link. This doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Thanks for your respons, to make it more clear: When I click the button I want to open a panel with a link to a page `/example-page` . To close the panel I want to click on the same button and to navigate to `/`

Comment: I see. Think you could stand up a small ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo for this code that we could inspect live?

Comment: I updatet my post with a codesandbox example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a state in the layout to hold a reference to an active artist and attach an `onClick` handler to each link to set the active artist value. The `to` prop would conditionally render the appropriate link target.

Example:

```
const [activeLink, setActiveLink] = useState(null);

const handleLink = (id) => () => {
  setActiveLink((active) => (active === id ? null : id));
};

...

<NavLink
  key={currentMotive.artist.slug.current}
  className={({ isActive }) => isActive ? "isActive" : "isNotActive"}
  to={activeLink === currentMotive.artist.slug.current
    ? `/motive/${currentMotive.slug.current}`
    : `artist/${currentMotive.artist.slug.current}`
  }
  onClick={handleLink(currentMotive.artist.slug.current)}
>
   {currentMotive.artist.name}
</NavLink>
```

Example from sandbox:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { NavLink, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

export default function RootLayout() {
  const [activeLink, setActiveLink] = useState(null);

  const handleLink = (id) => () => {
    setActiveLink((active) => (active === id ? null : id));
  };

  return (
    <div className="Root">
      <ul>
        Nav:
        <li>
          <NavLink
            to={activeLink === "artist-1" ? "/" : "artist/artist-1"}
            onClick={handleLink("artist-1")}
          >
            Artist 1
          </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li>
          <NavLink
            to={activeLink === "artist-2" ? "/" : "artist/artist-2"}
            onClick={handleLink("artist-2")}
          >
            Artist 2
          </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li>
          <NavLink
            to={activeLink === "artist-3" ? "/" : "artist/artist-3"}
            onClick={handleLink("artist-3")}
          >
            Artist 3
          </NavLink>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <div>
        <Outlet />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit how-to-change-the-path-when-navlink-is-active]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [useMatch](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-match) to check if the path is active.

```
const isActive = useMatch("artist/" + currentMotive.artist.slug.current);

<NavLink
   className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? "isActive" : "isNotActive")}
   to={isActive
      ? "/motive/" + currentMotive.slug.current
      : "artist/" + currentMotive.artist.slug.current}
   key={currentMotive.artist.slug.current}>
   {currentMotive.artist.name}
</NavLink>
```

Comment: You expect OP to do this for each `NavLink` component they may be using? Not very sustainable.

Comment: If there are more than one link, OP should use this example to create an iterative approach based on an array of links.